# Understanding the use of defaultdict in Python

Tags: python

I am starting to learn Python and have run across a piece of code that I'm hoping one of you can help me understand.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd_dict = defaultdict(dict)
dd_dict["Joel"]["City"] = "Seattle"
```

result:

```
{ "Joel" : { "City" : Seattle"}}
```

The part I am having a problem with is the third line. Could someone please explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: A `defaultdict` is a `dict` whose keys "default" to values if a key has not been set yet. You basically have a dictionary of a dictionary (third line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation of `defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

> If default_factory is not None, it is called without arguments to provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned.

Since `"Joel"` doesn't exist as key yet the `dd_dict["Joel"]` part creates an empty dictionary as value for the key `"Joel"`. The following part `["City"] = "Seattle"` is just like adding a normal key-value pair a dictionary - in this case the `dd_dict["Joel"]` dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

The third line inserts a dictionary inside a dictionary. By using dict as a default value in default dict you are telling python to initialize every new dd_dict value with an empty dict. The above code is equivalent to

```
dd_dict["Joel"] = {}
dd_dict['Joel"]["City"] = "Seattle"
```

If you didn't use default dict the second line would have raised a key error. So default dicts are a way of avoiding such errors by initializing the default value of your data structure.

Answer (score 2):

> The first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory
>   attribute; it defaults to None.  If default_factory is not None, it is
>   called without arguments to provide a default value for the given key,
>   this value is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned.

```
dd_dict = defaultdict(dict)
dd_dict["Joel"]["City"] = "Seattle"
```

in you case, when you call `dd_dict["Joel"]`, there is no such key in the `dd_dict`, this raises a `KeyError` exception. `defaultdict`  has `__missing__(key)` protocol to handle this error, when it can not find the key, it will call the `default_factory` without arguments to provide a default value for the given key.

so when you call `dd_dict["Joel"]`, this will give you a dict `{}`, then you add item `["City"] = "Seattle"` to the empty dict, someting like:

```
{}["City"] = "Seattle"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you access a key of a defaultdict that does not exits, you will get what the function you supply returns.

In your case you supplied `dict`, therefore you get a new empty dictionary:

```
>>> dict()
{}

>>> from collections import defaultdict
... dd_dict = defaultdict(dict)
...
>>> dd_dict['Joel']
{}
```

Now you add your key-value pair to this dictionary:

```
>>> dd_dict["Joel"]["City"] = "Seattle"
"Joel" : { "City" : Seattle"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a key is accessed and is missing, the `__missing__` method is accessed.

For a regular `dict`, a `KeyError` is raised

For a `defaultdict`, the object you passed as a parameter is created and accessed.

If you made a `defaultdict(list)`, and tried to access a missing key, you would get a list back.

Example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['missing']
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

defaultdict(dict) returns a dictionary object that will return an empty dictionary value if you index into it with a key that doesn't yet exist:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd_dict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> dd_dict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {})
>>> dd_dict["Joel"]
{}
>>> dd_dict["anything"]
{}
>>> dd_dict[99]
{}
```

So the third line creates a key-value pair ("Joel", {}) in dd_dict, then sets the ("City", "Seattle") key-value pair on the empty dictionary.

It's equivalent to:

```
>>> dd_dict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> dd_dict["Joel"] = {}
>>> dd_dict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Joel': {}})
>>> dd_dict["Joel"]["City"] = "Seattle"
>>> dd_dict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Joel': {'City': 'Seattle'}})
```